# Overlay over NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm stuck trying to solve the concept of having an overlay over a NavigationPage.

- NavigationPage holds different ContentPages stack-alike
- Overlay shows hints or a menu above the ContentPages

The Overlay should be independent of the ContentPages of the NavigationPage in a way that while switching the ContentPage (with animations) the Overlay should stay fixed and attached to the screen, so that any animation or whatever is happening in the ContentPages will have no effect on the overlay.

How can I implement such a behavior?

Would this be possible with a CustomRenderer for the NavigationPage? Or placing the NavigationPage into another Page, which has a RelativeLayout holding the Overlay and the NavigationPage?

Comment: Can you post some code structure or snapshot, what exactly you wish to achieve.

Comment: You might want to use single content page and animate ContentView manually

Comment: @Greensy that would work, but I would loose all the benefit of the NavigationPage (like Push/Pop, Animations etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came up with is to what @Greensy suggested. I implemented my own NavigationPage, which includes the animation independent Overlay.